# Jquery Check parent checkboxes in nested DIVs

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create nested DIvs containing checkboxes. I am now trying to get it so I can check a low level checkbox and it will check all the parents only back up to the highest level.

I want to use DIVs, because don't

Here is a working example using lists to manage nested checkboxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3y3Pb/17/

I'd like to reproduce this example using DIVs instead of lists, because I don't want to show the DIVs at once. I'm using a "+" sign in front of the Main Checkbox, if the user clicks in this sign it will pop up the Sub-options.

Here is my HTML with the DIVs:

```
<div>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome1' value='ValueA' > TextoGeral1
        </label>

        <font style='font-size: 10px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none' href='#div_classe_especifica_1' onClick='toggleClassEspecifica(1)'><span id='span_classe_especifica_1'>+</span></a>]</font> 
        <div style='display:none' id='div_classe_especifica_1'>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value1' > TextoEspecifico<br>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value2' > TextoEspecifico<br>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value3' > TextoEspecifico<br>
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome2' value='ValueB' > TextoGeral2
        </label>
        <font style='font-size: 10px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none' href='#div_classe_especifica_2' onClick='toggleClassEspecifica(2)'><span id='span_classe_especifica_2'>+</span></a>]</font>
        <div style='display:none' id='div_classe_especifica_2'>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value4' > TextoEspecifico<br>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value5' > TextoEspecifico<br>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value6' > TextoEspecifico<br>
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>

<script>
    function toggleClassEspecifica(cod){
        //"div_classe_especifica_"+cod
        if ($( "#div_classe_especifica_"+cod ).css("display")=="none"){
            $( "#div_classe_especifica_"+cod ).show( );
            $( "#span_classe_especifica_"+cod ).text("-");
        } else {
        $( "#div_classe_especifica_"+cod ).hide( );
            $( "#span_classe_especifica_"+cod ).text("+");
        }
    }
    </script>
```

My trial is the following:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
$(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
var sibs = false;
$(this).closest('div').each(function () {
    if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
})
$(this).parents('div').prev().prop('checked', sibs);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your `html` with `div`'s?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a list?

Comment: I want to use DIVs to toggle the visibility of the child DIVs if the user want to see the Sub-options